# Border radius CSS3

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

How's the best way to do this kind of border with only css3?[image: Border-radius]

P.S: The width is 100%, size of screen.

Comment: Is that just a border (or) a background? Looks like you have got some icons or something on top of it.

Comment: Forget about the icons, I was trying only make that border with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pseudo effects to create something like this:

```css
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  }
body:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-50%;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  border-radius:100%
  }
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  border-left:2vw solid black;
  border-right:2vw solid black;
  width:96vw;
  }
```

It's basically made using an idea such as:

```
          /----------------\  <-- oval shape
         /------------------\
        +--------------------+ <--top of screen
        |\                  /|
        | \________________/ |<--screen
```

With the body tag, the 'upper part' is now automatically hidden, leaving:

```
        +--------------------+ 
        |\                  /|
        | \________________/ |
```

you could then use another pseudo effect in order to add the 'black' borders to the left and right of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is with the following HTML:

```css
body {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
     }
    
    .content {
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: green;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">test</div>
```

However, you'll notice it's not quite smoothed off at the edges. If you want that effect, you'll need to extend the width of the div beyond 100%, start it before left: 0 and hide any content that is beyond a 100% width to remove the horizontal scrollbar.